# Android delete off screen imageViews

Tags: java, android

So I have a programatically created ImageView inside of a LinearLayout, and there are two buttons.

One button uses a TranslateAnimation to make the ImageView move left.
The other button uses a TranslateAnimation to make the ImageView move right.

I want it so that when the ImageView moves off screen, it is deleted.

I know there's a method called removeView where you can just pass the view into its parameters and the view gets deleted, but I have no clue how to check if the ImageView is off-screen or not.

So in a nutshell, this is what I want to do

```
if(imageView.isOffScreen()){
     linearLayout.removeView(imageView);
}
```

Except, isOffScreen() isn't a real method, and I couldn't find any method for ImageViews that would check if it was off screen.

TLDR :
How can I check whether or not an ImageView is off-screen? (And by off-screen, I mean you can't see it anymore on the phone screen.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a TranslateAnimation, if you already know that by the end of the animation your view will be off the screen, then you can set up an AnimationListener that will remove the View from the view tree when the animation is finished.

```
yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation anim) {};

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation anim) {};

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
        linearLayout.removeView(imageView);
    };

});
```

This way you won't have to check the location of the view at any point, you can simply remove it when the animation is done.

As an aside, is there a reason you want to remove the view, instead of setting Visibilty to GONE?

Comment: I would assume it would be better (performance wise) to delete the entire imageView rather than change its visibility to GONE.

Comment: That depends on a number of factors.  While a View being GONE will still be visited during the render cycle, it will not have any work to do.  Removing the view though, assuming all references to it are gone, will make it eligible for garbage collection, which itself poses the potential to make the app feel more chunky and less responsive.  Anyway, does the AnimationListener suit your purpose?